# No route found for "GET /lucky/number/"

Tags: php, symfony-3.4

I'm trying to follow the Symfony tutorial in order to create my very first page and I'm having a little issue over here. The skeleton of the project was created using composer, `composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton`.

As a server I'm using `nginx` with `php-fpm` version 7.0.

Here I have my `LuckyController` located in `src/AppBundle/Controller`

```
namespace App\AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class LuckyController 
{

    /**
     *@Route("/lucky/number")
     */
    public function numberAction()
    {
        $number = random_int(0, 100);

        return new Response(
            '<html><body>Lucky number: '.$number.'</body></html>'
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: have you tried clearing the cache? (bin/console cache:clear)

Comment: @Jakumi I just do it, and the problem is still unsolved.

Comment: okay, I'd suggest trying `bin/console cache:warmup` and if that also doesn't help, either the route is not being read, check by `bin/console router` sub commands, and finally trying to match /lucky/number, and checking the config files ...

Comment: Can you please tell us the error you are receiving? Is it a 403 error? A 401 error? Have you configured ngnix appropriately?